# Do not show null element with Symfony serializer

Tags: php, xml, symfony, serialization

So I have many classes I want to serialize with Symfony serializer. For instance

```
class Foo
{
  public $apple = 1;
  public $pear = null;

  public function serialize() {
    Utils::serialize($this);
  }
}
```

which I serialize with the following `serialize()` call :

```
class Utils {
    public static function serialize($object) {
      $encoder = new XmlEncoder();
      $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
      $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
      $str = $serializer->serialize($object, 'xml')
    }
}
```

The output produced gives me:

```
<apple>1</apple><pear/>
```

The output expected should be:

```
<apple>1</apple>
```

I took a look at the [Symfony 2.8 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/serializer.html) and managed to find a quick solution by using `$normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes("pear")`.

So the improved serialize static function looks like this

```
class Utils {
  public static function ignoreNullAttributes($object) {
    $ignored_attributes = array();
    foreach($object as $member => $value) {
      if (is_null($object->$member)) {
        array_push($ignored_attributes, $member);
      }
     }
     return $ignored_attributes;
   }

    public static function serialize($object) {
      $encoder = new XmlEncoder();
      $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
      $normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(Utils::ignoreNullAttributes($object));
      $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
      $str = $serializer->serialize($object, 'xml')
    }
}
```

However, this solution does not satisfy me since I have more complicated cases where different `Foo` can be owned by a same class. e.g.

```
class Bar
{
  public $foo1; // (apple=null; pear=2)
  public $foo2; // (apple=2; pear=null)

  public function serialize() {
    Utils::serialize($this);
  }
}
```

Here I cannot use the `setIgnoredAttributes` method since `$foo1` and `$foo2` do not have the same null elements. Furthermore, I do not call the `serialize` method from the child class (i.e. `Foo`) here so the `setIgnoredAttributes` is empty.

Without having to write complex introspection code, how can I hide by default null element with Symfony 2.8 serializer ? I have seen for instance that it is enabled by default with [JMSSerializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/293).

Comment: I'm afraid that there isn't an easy way to do it (_without having to write complex introspection code_), adding `elseif (null === $val) { return false; }` here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Encoder/XmlEncoder.php#L489 resolves your problem, but to do that you need rewrite a lot of code because almost all methods are private into `XmlEncoder` :(

Comment: Never used it but maybe using JMS serializer could help with that http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle hope it helps

Comment: @Yonel thanks indeed I would like to avoid to write in symfony code. I am not alone ! Isn't it possible to override the XmlEncoder in a non intruisive way for that ?

Comment: @Thomas as you see at the end of my question I am aware of JMS serializer. I want to stick with Symfony one.

Comment: Well I found you a simple solution  \o/  :)

Comment: Let me know if it works for you

Comment: @Yonel thank you I m currently taking a look :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A solution would be to extend from `ObjectNormalizer` class, override the `normalize()` method and remove all `null` values there:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;

class CustomObjectNormalizer extends ObjectNormalizer
{
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = parent::normalize($object, $format, $context);

        return array_filter($data, function ($value) {
            return null !== $value;
        });
    }
}

$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new CustomObjectNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

// ...
```

If we have an array of [Person like the one of the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#serializing-an-object):

```
// ...

$person1 = new Person();
$person1->setName('foo');
$person1->setAge(null);
$person1->setSportsman(false);

$person2 = new Person();
$person2->setName('bar');
$person2->setAge(33);
$person2->setSportsman(null);

$persons = array($person1, $person2);
$xmlContent = $serializer->serialize($persons, 'xml');

echo $xmlContent;
```

The result will be those not `null` nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <item key="0">
        <name>foo</name>
        <sportsman>0</sportsman>
    </item>
    <item key="1">
        <name>bar</name>
        <age>33</age>
    </item>
</response>
```

Comment: This works like a charm and this is a very simple solution. Too bad I cannot vote twice ! Thank you :)

Comment: @coincoin +1 :)

Comment: It’s even easier to implement and test by composing an instance of `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer` into a simple implementation of `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface` with the suggested filtering above - less baggage, fully tested.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better solution also since November 2016 with this feature : [[Serializer] XmlEncoder : Add a way to remove empty tags](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20398)

You just have to put the context parameter `remove_empty_tags` to true like [this example](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/4644ee91e871200d658cd241dc0275e8f238814d#diff-0590165d9e66621f7d21653e42d21f65R148)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AbstractObjectNormalizer::SKIP_NULL_VALUES` flag to skip null values when normalizing:

```
$json = $serializer->serialize(
    $user,
    JsonEncoder::FORMAT,
    [AbstractObjectNormalizer::SKIP_NULL_VALUES => true]
);
```

Source: https://lindevs.com/skip-null-values-during-serialization-in-symfony/